# override abstract enum method

Tags: groovy, enums

The following is valid Java code:

```
enum ProductType {
  CASH_BONUS { 

     void doSomething() {}    
  },

  CUSTOMIZABLE { 
     void doSomething() {}    
  }

  abstract void doSomething()
}
```

But when I try to run this in the Groovy console, I get the errors:

> Can't have an abstract method in a
>   non-abstract class. The class
>   'ProductType' must be declared
>   abstract or the method 'void
>   doSomething()' must be implemented. 
>   at line: -1, column: -1
>
> Can't have an abstract method in a
>   non-abstract class. The class
>   'ProductType' must be declared
>   abstract or the method 'void
>   doSomething()' must not be abstract. 
>   at line: 11, column: 3

I seem to recall reading that Groovy does not (yet) support overriding methods for enum constants, is this correct, and if so, is there an elegant way to emulate this behavior?

### Update

This was a bug that was fixed some time around Groovy 1.8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4641

you can make the abstract method not abstract. throw an exception to make sure you always override it like:

```
enum ProductType {
    CASH_BONUS(1) {
        void doSomething() {
        }
    },
    CUSTOMIZABLE(2) {
        void doSomething() {
        }
    };
    ProductType(int n) {
        this.n=n;
    }
    final int n;
    void doSomething() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}

ProductType.CASH_BONUS.doSomething();
ProductType.CUSTOMIZABLE.doSomething();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if you define constructor arguments for your Enum. Otherwise it's a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Groovy Compile from 1.8 to 2.0 in eclipse worked for me

(Eclipse 3.7)